# How to create a Paragraph (<p>) using HtmlGenericControl in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

How to create a pragraph <p> tag in ASP.NET using the HtmlGenericControl class?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
HtmlGenericControl para = new HtmlGenericControl ( "p" );
```

Although I would leave it as a container control for the extra properties/methods.

```
HtmlContainerControl para = (HtmlContainerControl)new HtmlGenericControl ( "p" );
```

Comment: HtmlContainerControl is an abstract class. I think it should be : HtmlContainerControl para = new HtmlGenericControl("p"). Thank, you put me on the right way to find answer to my problem.

Comment: I turned those around.  Fixed.

Answer (score 4):

I know, maybe is not the fastest way to implement, but I used to write "missing" html controls to be reusable later, via code, without messing around with html tags.

```
Public Class HtmlParagraph
    Inherits HtmlControl

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New("p")
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub AddParsedSubObject(ByVal obj As Object)
        If (TypeOf obj Is LiteralControl) Then
            Me._text = DirectCast(obj, LiteralControl).Text
        Else
            MyBase.AddParsedSubObject(obj)
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub Render(ByVal writer As HtmlTextWriter)
        writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Fieldset)
        If (Me.HasControls) Then
            Me.RenderChildren(writer)
        ElseIf (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Me._text)) Then
            writer.Write(Me._text)
        End If
        writer.RenderEndTag()
    End Sub


    Private pText As String = String.Empty
    <Category("Appearance"), PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerDefaultProperty), Localizable(True), DefaultValue(""), DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)> _
    Public Overridable Property [Text]() As String
        Get
            If (Me.pText Is Nothing) Then Return String.Empty Else Return Me.pText
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Me.pText = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Comment: I think you mean writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.P) rather than Fieldset.

Answer (score -7):

```
new HtmlGenericControl("p");
```

PS. Try using Intellisense...

Comment: Could someone please explain the reason for all the downvotes?